# Django Rest Framework - Create and Update Parent-Child relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to use the Django Rest Framework serializers to make API's for my front-end to create / update and delete articles in a store. These articles can have multiple prices (depending on time). So there is a one-to-many relation from article (one) to price (many). I have defined this in `models.py`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Article ID")
    article_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Name")
    article_order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Order")

class Price(models.Model):
    price_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Price ID")
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Article ID", related_name="Prices")
    price_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Price")
```

My serializers.py file looks like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('price_price',)

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    Prices = PriceSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        prices_data = validated_data.pop('Prices')
        article = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for price_data in prices_data:
            Price.objects.create(article_id=article, **price_data)
        return article

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        prices_data = validated_data.pop('Prices')
        Article.objects.filter(article_id=instance.article_id).update(**validated_data)
        for price_data in prices_data:
            Price.objects.get_or_create(article_id=instance, **price_data)
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

This works perfectly and I can create a new article-price measurement with this data: (`article_order` will be used later for ordering the list)

```
{"Prices":[{"price_price":"1"}],"article_name":"Article A","article_order":"1"}
```

Until this point, everything is working as expected. But when I try to update the prices, the `Price.objects.get_or_create()` statement does not recognize existing prices. For example: when the first price is €10, then €20 and then again €10, the last price will not be inserted because the `get_or_create` statement does not recognize this as a new instance of the `price` model. That probably makes sense, because the `PriceSerializer` does not serialize the `price_id`. But when I change the serializer to:

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = '__all__
```

, I can no longer create instances because the `ArticleSerializer` is requiring an `article_id` for the `Price` instance (but that doesn't exist yet).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? The DRF documentation only includes the create statement for this type of nested serializer.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the `get_or_create` method correctly. 
It accepts `kwargs` which are used to lookup the object and if it does not exist, creates them, adding other field values from `defaults`.

This means that if you pass the new values to update as `kwargs`, it won't find such object because it currently has different values for those fields. 
Instead, you should pass in fields that do not change in `kwargs` and the rest in `defaults`.

This is what you should do

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    prices_data = validated_data.pop('Prices')
    Article.objects.filter(article_id=instance.article_id).update(**validated_data)
    for price_data in prices_data:
        Price.objects.get_or_create(article_id=instance, defaults=price_data)
    return instance
```

Note however, that you may get a `MutipleObjectsReturned` error since an article can have several prices based on your DB architecture. You may want to change the `article_id` to a `OneToOneField` to prevent this if mutiple prices per Article was not intended.

You can read more about `get_or_create` in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

As a side note, in OOP architecture `id` in `Article` already implies article id, so prepending `article` to your field names is a really redundant and bad practice. And again, you may want to use the Django autogenerated id field instead of redefining it, unless you want to customize it in some way, which is currently not obvious in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can see from Django REST Framework documentation here about [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

```
 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
     instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
     instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
     instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
     return instance
```

I hope it can help you.